# Join two tables based on the first table id

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like this

table A:

```
   ID NAME
    1  TED
    2  JIM
    3  AJU
    4  ANN
```

Table B :

```
ID AGE
1  12
2  14
3  15
4  13
5  15
6  13
7  12
8  16
9  14
10 12
```

And I want output like

```
ID    NAME   AGE
1     TED    12
2     JIM    14
3     AJU    15
4     ANN    13
```

Comment: Look up JOIN (Transact-SQL) and try something yourself first. Post what you have tried. Other users aren't here to do your work for you, we're here to help you when you have questions, or get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Do a simple Query and you will get your result

```
Select A.ID,A.NAME,(Select B.AGE FROM B WHERE B.ID = A.ID)
FROM A
```

Another way to do that

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,B.AGE 
FROM A JOIN B 
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: table A:
 

       ID NAME
        1  TED
        2  JIM
        3  AJU
        4  ANN
        5  JIN
        6  JOE
        7  SEN
        8  WEE
        


Table B :

    ID AGE
    1  12
    2  14
    3  15
    4  13
    

And I want output like:

    ID    NAME   AGE
    1     TED    12
    2     JIM    14
    3     AJU    15
    4     ANN    13
    5     JIN    NULL
    6     JOE    NULL
    7     SEN    NULL
    8     WEE    NULL
 and how about this output?

Comment: Please comment using correct Indentation or using correct format.
By See your comment its not possible what you want to say??

Answer (score 1):

You want to join these two tables and return all common entries present in both tables(sets), joins are done based on some common entity(usually keys), in your case it is the column 'ID' .

- An inner join of A and B gives the result of A intersect B, i.e. the inner part of a Venn diagram intersection.

  ```
  select A.*,B.age
   from tablea A
      inner join tableb b
           on a.id = b.id
  ```

Answer (score 0):

just do a simple join

```
SELECT
        A.*
        B.Age
        FROM TABLEA A
            INNER JOIN TABLEB B
                ON A.ID = B.ID
```